# how to loop from 0000 to 9999 and convert the number to the relative string?

Tags: python, string, numbers

i want to get some string, range from 0000 to 9999, that's to say, i want to print the following string:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
....
9999
```

i tried to use `print "\n".join([str(num) for num in range(0, 9999)])`, but failed, i get the following number:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
9999
```

i want python to add the prefix ***0*** automatically, making the number remain ***4 bit digits*** all the time. can anyone give a hand to me? any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't get a sequence ending in "9999" with range(0, 9999); Python ranges don't include the upper bound.  Use range(10**4) if you want to include 9999.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One way to get what you want is to use string formatting:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     '{0:04}'.format(i)
... 
'0000'
'0001'
'0002'
'0003'
'0004'
'0005'
'0006'
'0007'
'0008'
'0009'
```

So to do what you want, do this:

```
print("\n".join(['{0:04}'.format(num) for num in range(0, 10000)]))
```

Comment: No it is not a perfect solution. Major flaw there. If you are going to be using big ranges like 9999 then you should use `xrange` to avoid allocating the whole list of numbers. It may not make a big difference to do it once or twice, but what if that loop is inside another loop inside some recursive function calls?

Comment: What Michael said plus remove [] (use gen exp instead of list comp).

Comment: @MichaelDillon, that's only true in Python 2. In Python 3, `range` == `xrange` and `xrange` is undefined. The OP used `range`, so I assumed that he's using Python 3.

Comment: @yak, that's also depends on circumstances. Using a genex saves memory but is actually a bit slower in this case. On my machine, anyway.

Comment: @senderle: The `print` statement that he used and you copied is a dead giveaway for Python 2, though.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, good point -- I didn't catch the inconsistency, not having used Python 3 very much at the time.

Comment: Many years down the road, Python 3 is the norm, so I changed it back to `range`!

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill

> Return the numeric string left filled with zeros in a string of length
>   width. A sign prefix is handled correctly. The original string is
>   returned if width is less than or equal to len(s).

E.g.:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...   print('{:d}'.format(i).zfill(4))
... 
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
print"\n".join(["%#04d" % num for num in range(0, 9999)])
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply using [str.rjust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rjust#str.rjust):

```
print "\n".join([str(num).rjust(4, '0') for num in range(0, 1000)])
```

> Return the string right justified in a string of length width. Padding
>   is done using the specified fillchar (default is an ASCII space). The
>   original string is returned if width is less than or equal to len(s).

Answer (score 2):

[str.zfill](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=zfill#str.zfill) also works:

`print('\n'.join([str(num).zfill(4) for num in range(0, 10000)]))`

Answer (score 1):

another way to do that:

```
["%.4d" % i for i in range(0,999)]
```

or

```
["%04d" % i for i in range(0,999)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for i in range(9999):
    print(str(i).zfill(4)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick of left-padding the string:

```
(lambda f: f(f))(lambda f: (lambda x: (x if len(x) == 4 else f(f)('0' + x))))(str(num))
```